# Javascript -> Attempting to dynamically add radio buttons from an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

So I'm working on my very first 'real' JavaScript project -> the famed Quiz app :)

I'm passing questions and answers via an array, and I want make sure to allow for a variable number of answer options.  To do this, I'm using a For loop and the createElement method to add and populate the appropriate HTML for each answer in the array.  To my eyes, what I've built actually works great.  And after running the function I can see the resultant HTML elements in the right place and with all the appropriate tagging in my console.  However, the inner DIV text won't render on screen!  Very confused.  What am I missing?  Please help!

My JS code:

```
<body>

<form id="form1">
</form>

<script>
    var answers = ["answer1", "answer2", "answer3", "answer4", "answer5"];

    function createRadioButtonFromArray(array) {
        var len = array.length;
        var form = document.getElementById("form1");
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){
            var radio = document.createElement("input");
                radio.type = "radio";
                radio.name = "choices";
                radio.class = "radioButtons";
                radio.value = i;
                radio.id = "choice" + i;
            var radioText = document.createElement("div");
                radioText.id = "c" + i;
                radioText.class = "choiceText";

            form.appendChild(radio);
            radio.appendChild(radioText);

            document.getElementById("c" + i).innerHTML=array[i];


        }
    }
</script>

</body>
```

And here's a screenshot of my console AFTER I run the function, for reference:

[image]

Comment: You can't have a `div` inside an input tag

Comment: Oh!  So I should add it after the input?

Comment: That totally worked, thanks!

Comment: If you want to add class to html elements you should use `radio.className = "radioButtons";` instead of `radio.class` and same with `radioText`

Comment: I actually have another question, perhaps you know the answer.  Why aren't my radio.class and radioText.class properties showing up when all the others do?

Comment: @Givi Thanks!  Why is that?  Guessing it's because 'class' is a JS reserved word?

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.className) "The name className is used for this property instead of class because of conflicts with the "class" keyword in many languages which are used to manipulate the DOM."

Comment: Note: If you want to add multiply classes to an element, would be better if you use [element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList) property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're plan is nearly working but Input elements have no content! So the div's will not be rendered at all!

Create a `div` that contains your radio button and the input text on the same level:

```
var radio = document.createElement("input");
    radio.type = "radio";
    radio.name = "choices";
    radio.class = "radioButtons";
    radio.value = i;
    radio.id = "choice" + i;
var radioText = document.createElement("div");
    radioText.id = "c" + i;
    radioText.class = "choiceText";
    radioText.innerHTML = array[i];

radioText.appendChild(radio);
form.appendChild(radioText);
```

Comment: I actually tried something slightly different, which seems to work.  Anything wrong with it as opposed to your solution? `form.appendChild(radio);
    form.appendChild(radioText);`

Comment: No, as you append them in the correct order it will work! But if you want to style the text and the radio button having both in a div is easier!

Answer (score 0):

Add label after or before radio button. Label will let you check radio button by clicking on it's text

```
var radio = document.createElement("input");
    radio.type = "radio";
    radio.name = "choices";
    radio.class = "radioButtons";
    radio.value = i;
    radio.id = "choice" + i;
var radioText = document.createElement("label");
    radioText.id = "c" + i;
    radioText.setAttribute("for", "choice" + i);
    radioText.class = "choiceText";

form.appendChild(radio);
form.appendChild(radioText);

document.getElementById("c" + i).innerHTML=array[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

`<input>` cannot contain any DOM elements or DOM nodes. But if you want to have checkboxes associated with some text, I suggest you to use `<input>` with `<label for="">` where `label.for` is name of `input` element. For combining them you can put them into some container(i.e. `<div>`):

By default on label with set property `for` raises click event on  element with the same `name` property value as `for` property value. This means that you do not need to add additional click event handlers for `<label>` elements.

```
var checkId = 1;

var container = document.createElement("div");

var radio = document.createElement("input");
    radio.type = "radio";
    radio.name = "choices"+checkId;
    radio.class = "radioButtons";
    radio.value = i;
    radio.id = "choice" + i;
var label = document.createElement("label");
    label.innerHTML = array[i];
    // Set attribute for
    label.setAttribute("for","choices"+checkId);

//Increase counter for check element name.
checkId++;

container.appendChild(radio);
container.appendChild(label);

form.appendChild(container);
```